# How to do an element that is toggable on small screen sizes but always visible on big

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I want to have a menu that is toggable in small screen sizes and always visible on medium sizes upwards.

The behavior should be (basically) exactly like this [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/2e3pup0u/5/).

The steps are:

- Go to a small screen size (til the body outline is gold)
- Check that it's toggable
- When the menu is hidden and you get a bigger screen size, the menu should appear
- When the menu is not hidden, go to a bigger screen size and it should remain shown
- When on a big screen size, and element was hidden, you should see it but when you drag to a smaller size, it should get hidden
- When on a big screen size, and element was NOT hidden, you should see it but when you drag to a smaller size, it should get hidden

To achieve this is very easy with:

```
$(".click").click(function() {
  $(".menu").toggleClass("hidden-md-down");
});
```

My problem now is that I want to animate this show and hide and I can't do it with the class toggle.

So I have to rely on for example [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and here is where my problem lies, see [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/2e3pup0u/6/).

If you now go to a small screen size, hide the menu and make the window size bigger, the `menu` won't appear because of the hide() function.

I know this could be solve with a `$(window).resize` but I definitely don't want that solution since it's terrible for performance for such a small feature.

So how can I either have this toggle class with an animation or do it with js without the resize method?

Comment: try this: http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/08/using-css3-to-provide-smooth-resize-effects/

Comment: imagine the ux involved in a animated meniu swich

Comment: Use a throttled resize, like http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/cTZJU/ ... it has little to none performance impact and is well explained here: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: For best performance wire your window size check to only the end of the browser resize, not to every stage.

Comment: You can play with the `input-label` and the `focus` states of the input in your media queries to get closer to a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've put my comment into an answer instead: "For best performance wire your window size check to only the end of the browser resize, not to every stage."

This code works and it only runs .5 sec after the end of the window resize event rather than during (better performance). Run the code full page and squeeze your browser window to see it in action.

Instead of sending the text values #width and #height you can elect to run your menu toggle or deactivate it; I'd do this by removing the js class you're using to activate the menu initially.

And make your menu an unordered list and set it to be inline on desktop and an unbulleted list on mobile using css.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
    }, 500);
});

$(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
    var widthReport = $("#width").text($(this).width());
    var heightReport = $("#height").text($(this).height());
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="width"></div>
<div id="height"></div>
```

Comment: Is there no way around this? I know this technique but I'd rather not use it.

Comment: This is the way around the issue you're describing with window resize performance. It checks only at the end, not every change.

Comment: You get un up-vote but I won't accept your answer for now because I'd rather not have that many js lines for such a trivial task, if it's the only way around I'll accept your answer later, thank you!

Comment: Your task requires a toggle event which only css can't handle. However, if you let go of that requirement, all you need for this is media queries.